# AWS API Gateway changes OAS3 path and query parameter types to string

Tags: swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-sam

When creating an API Gateway using an `OAS3` definition, the path and query parameter types get changed to strings. I can't find any AWS documentation stating the expected behavior or why this is. I know when configuring the API Gateway manually it doesn't expose a `type` for path/query variables, but is there a way to get API Gateway to keep the  `OAS3` path/query parameter type for documentation sake?

We're trying to use the Serverless Developer Portal to host our API documentation and we need to expose the correct parameter types; e.g. for a `limit` query parameter we need it to display as an `integer`.

Here's a SAM for a basic example. The path parameter `param` is an `integer` and the swagger generated documentation displays it correctly, however API Gateway changes it to a `string` and the generated documentation shows it as a `string`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  ComplexityScoreProxy:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      DefinitionBody:
        openapi: 3.0.1
        info:
          version: "1"
          title: Aws API Gateway Boolean Test
        paths:
          /{param}:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: http_proxy
                uri: https://example.com
                httpMethod: GET
                responses:
                  "200":
                    statusCode: 200
              parameters:
                - name: param
                  in: path
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: integer
              responses:
                "200":
                  description: OK
```

Put the SAM in tempalte.yaml and run cloudformation to deploy:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template.yaml --stack-name boolean-test
```

Get the ID

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query "items[?name=='Aws API Gateway Boolean Test'].id"
```

Retrieve the OAS replacing the `--rest-api-id` with the correct id:

```
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway' --rest-api-id XXXXXXXXXX --stage-name dev --export-type swagger latestoas.json
```

The exported OAS3 definition shows the parameter as a string:

```
 "paths" : {
    "/{param}" : {
      "get" : {
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "param",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        } ],
```

Also, viewing the generated swagger documentation in the Serverless Developer Portal displays the `param` as a `string`.

Comment: It also converts enums to plain string. If you use oas3 and base paths the published swagger won't work as is with tools like postman or openapi-generator because it produces a double-slash in the url. There are a bunch of other bugs. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis

Comment: Encountering the same issue now with a limit parameter of ```type: integer``` being imported as a string. Anyone come across resolution for this in the 2 years since this post?